# How would I make a Paleo yogurt-based frozen custard?

Tags: eggs, ice-cream, yogurt, honey, custard

OK, I've been tasked with making a Paleo dessert, and I'd like to try to make a frozen dessert. Here are the ground rules for Paleo desserts: only fermented dairy (yogurt is fine, milk and cream are not), only honey and maybe palm sugar as sweeteners, eggs are fine, nuts are fine, raw coconut oil is fine.

I'm thinking it might be possible to combine full-fat yogurt, strained perhaps, with egg yolks and honey, bring it up to 170 to make a custard, then chill, to get something that would freeze acceptably in a standard home ice cream machine.

Any suggestions? Would this work? I'd think it would taste good, especially with some chopped almonds and berries mixed in, but I'm worried about texture. What issues will I have with using honey as the sole sweetener? Will there be enough fat in the yogurt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frozen yogurt made with full fat yogurt is very creamy and full flavored. You might find that the eggs are unnecessary.

If you do do the custard watch you temperature carefully as yogurt curdles easily when it is heated. If you have a lot of fat in the yogurt then it will be resistant to curdling otherwise you can take out some insurance by mixing in a little bit of corn starch- if that is allowed.

Honey is perfectly fine and many frozen yogurt recipes call for it.

Comment: I ended up with a recipe of 3 egg yolks, 12 oz of Greek (strained) yogurt, and 1.8 oz of honey. Whisked the yogurt and honey together over a double boiler, then tempered into the eggs and mixed, then heated the whole thing up to custard temp (170) and cooled. Made a pretty good, smooth-textured, if simple-tasting, frozen custard! Will want some other components for balance. The honey-only sweetening was fine.